# How to find the destination (targetline) of agents/pedestrians in anylogic?

Tags: java, anylogic

Now I use pedsource to generate pedestrians in Main, and set 4 targetlines. Pedestrians will walk between these targetlines.
I want to get the data about the destination of these pedestrians (which targetline that each pedestrian moves towards).
Is there any code to get this data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various calls for pedestrians to get their target location:
[image]

If you need to get the `TargetLine` that is set when they enter a "Ped move to" block, you can use a manual approach to store that in the ped agent type when it enters the "Ped move to" block:

1. add a variable of type `TargetLine` to your ped agent type
2. when peds decide which target line to use, also store it into the new variable as well

Comment: I tried getTargetX(), but it does not get the X-coordinate of targetline I set. For example, if I let pedestrians move to one targetline (x = 700), the getTargetX() will get X around 400 or 300.

Comment: Then you may need to use option 2 :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, I don't clearly understand option 2. If I set the variable in ped agent type, how can I get the data in Main? I mean, I want to collect the data of targetline in a data set.